# How to automatically generate a web UI from a REST API

Tags: api, frontend

Is there any solution to automatically generate a web UI from a REST API?

I found Swagger codegen but it generates a client for the API, not a UI.
I need a basic UI, allowing directly from the browser to use the different endpoints and display the response prettily. Something like a basic Postman that would be directly integrated into my website.

I don't have constraint about how the generation is done. Can be done once at build time, or at runtime on server side or on client side.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: i made some tests using https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about retool.com, it seems to do what you need.